# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

[image]

Creating Django REST FRamework API. Using Abstract User and email is the default logging parameter using.

AttributeError at /post/

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'email'.

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category  = ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')
    author = UserSerializer(source='user.email')
    #question = serializers.CharField(source='question.text', read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", max_length=254, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']



class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='email')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categorys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    rating = models.IntegerField("Rumor Rate", validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)], default=1, null=True)
    created = models.DateTime[![enter image description here][1]][1]Field(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to return the author's email in the author field when you request the `Post` endpoint. You may also convert the `author` field in the serializer to a `ReadOnlyField` (as `category`) and specify `source='author.email'`, since your model foreign key is named like that:

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')
    author = ReadOnlyField(source='author.email')

    # ...
```